# seg fault when calling virtual function of struct

Tags: c++, struct, segmentation-fault

I have a C++ code below which create an array of pointers to a struct

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

#define WATCH(x) std::cout << #x << ": " << x << std::endl;

typedef struct
{
    double  thickness;
    char    name[80];
    virtual double getDensity() const {return 0.1;}
} mat_prop_t;

struct mat_el_prop : public mat_prop_t
{
    double  density;
    double  young;
    double  poisson;
    virtual double getDensity() const {return density;}
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    mat_prop_t**            mat_prop;
    mat_prop = (mat_prop_t**) calloc(1, sizeof(mat_prop_t*));
    mat_prop[0] = (mat_prop_t*) calloc(1, sizeof(mat_el_prop));
    mat_el_prop* mat1 = (mat_el_prop*) mat_prop[0];
    mat1->density = 2.038735;
    mat1->young = 2.0;
    mat1->poisson = 0.3;
    mat1->thickness = 1.0;
    WATCH(mat1->density)
    WATCH(mat1->getDensity())

    free(mat_prop[0]);
    free(mat_prop);

    return 0;
}
```

I think the construct is correct, but it gives a seg fault error at line

```
WATCH(mat1->getDensity())
```

However, when the `virtual` keyword is removed, the code runs fine. Could anybody help to explain to me why?

Comment: Stop using `C` constructs such as `calloc` in a C++ program.  Also, `typedef struct` is a holdover from `C` code.  I think you need to read C++ material, and put the `C` stuff away.

Answer (score 2):

`calloc()` can only be used to allocate space for primitive types and POD structures. Since your struct has a virtual function, it's not POD, so you need to use `new` to ensure that the vtable is created properly.

```
mat_prop_t **mat_prop = new mat_prop_t*[1];
mat_prop[0] = new mat_el_prop;
mat_el_prop *mat1 = mat_prop[0];
```

You could technically use `calloc()` for `mat_prop`, since it's an array of pointers. But in C++ you should generally use `new`, not the C memory allocation functions.

Comment: This is valid. Now I know that for a struct containing a virtual needs to use new for mem allocation

Comment: @kstn In C++ you should just use `new` all the time, `malloc()` is for C.